# <rish:datascroller> not working fine, showing first page only

Tags: jsf

`<rish:datascroller>` not working fine, showing first page only

```
<div>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{topicListServiceDataBinder.isImage}">
        <img class="#{forExport ? 'image-table-export' : ''}" src="#{topicListServiceDataBinder.imageUrl}" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not topicListServiceDataBinder.isImage}">
        <div class="#{forExport ? 'export-textwidth' : ''}">
            <h3>#{topicListServiceDataBinder.tableTitle}</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="#{forExport ? 'topic-list-version' : ''}">
            #{labels.version_Number_Label} #{topicListServiceDataBinder.versionNumber} 
            #{labels.version_Date_Label}&#160;<h:outputText value="#{topicListServiceDataBinder.versionDate}" converter="DateConverter" />
            <h:outputText value=" (#{labels.version_Targetdate_Label}: "/>
            <h:outputText value="#{topicListServiceDataBinder.targetDate}" converter="MonthAndYearConverter" />
            <h:outputText value=")"/>
        </div>

        <h:form id="form_#{reportWrapper}">
            <rich:dataTable 
                id="list_#{reportWrapper}" 
                styleClass="list list_#{reportWrapper}"
                rows="15"
                columnClasses="colNo,,,colNo,colNo,colNo,colNo,colNo"
                columnsWidth="40px,50px,580px,40px,50px,55px,55px,55px"
                value="#{topicListServiceDataBinder.tableData.tableRows}" var="row"
                rowClasses="odd-row,even-row">

                <!-- column 1: rank -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{labels.rank}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.rank}" />
                </rich:column> 

                <!-- column 2: defect code -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{labels.vfc}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <a href="#" onclick="openDetails_#{reportWrapper}('#{row.valueList[0]}', '#{row.valueList[8]}', '#{row.valueList[9]}');return false;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{row.valueList[0]}" />
                    </a>
                </rich:column>

                <!-- column 3: description -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{labels.description}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.valueList[1]}" />
                </rich:column> 

                <!-- column 4: module -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{labels.modul}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.valueList[2]}" />
                </rich:column> 

                <!-- column 5: Abd % -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{kpi=='GWKPK24' ? labels.contribution_costs : labels.contribution_cases}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.valueList[3]}" />
                </rich:column> 

                <!-- column 6: Spot -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{kpi=='GWKPK24' ? labels.spot_24_k : labels.spot_24_f}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.valueList[4]}" converter="DecimalConverter3" />
                </rich:column> 

                <!-- column 7: Start -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{kpi=='GWKPK24' ? labels.start_24_k : labels.start_24_f}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.valueList[5]}" converter="DecimalConverter3" />
                </rich:column> 

                <!-- column 8: Plan -->
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{kpi=='GWKPK24' ? labels.plan_24_k : labels.plan_24_f}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.valueList[6]}" converter="DecimalConverter3" />
                </rich:column>

            </rich:dataTable>

            <input type="hidden" name="reportWrapper" value="#{reportWrapper}" />
            <rich:dataScroller style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px" for="list_#{reportWrapper}" maxPages="10" rendered="#{!forExport}" fastStep="10"/>
        </h:form>   
    </h:panelGroup>

    <rich:jQuery selector=".list_#{reportWrapper} tr" event="mouseover" query="jQuery(this).addClass('active-row')" attachType="live" />
    <rich:jQuery selector=".list_#{reportWrapper} tr" event="mouseout" query="jQuery(this).removeClass('active-row')" attachType="live" />

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question .. it is unclear what your problem is and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: In above code i am trying to display data page wise, at first time when page will load data will displayed properly when you click on 2nd page table will not refresh.

Comment: @RoopeshRana you should include full information of your problem with relevant explanation (code compulsary) in question body only not in comments.

Comment: There is <rich:datascroller> jsf tag, which I used to display data table page wise, but problem is some time this code works for one or two links, when i will get "TypeError: $ is not a function" then pagination will not work.